# how to read all lines from a file in ansible playbook

Tags: linux, loops, ansible, yaml, theforeman

I have a file called packages.txt which contains a list of packages. I have to read each line of that package.txt through my ansible file rpm.yml. Here is my code

```
- hosts: myhost
  tasks:

     - name: RPM Filter
       theforeman.foreman.content_view_filter:
         username: "admin"
         password: "admin"
         server_url: "myhost"
         name: "rpm filter"
         organization: "myorg"
         content_view: "My content view"
         filter_type: "rpm"
         package_name: "{{ item }}"
         inclusion: True
       loop:
         - packages.txt
```

My packages.txt contains these

```
open-ssh
nginx
grafana
vim
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an additional task to read the file. The simplest way would be to `cat` the file and `register` into a variable. Then this variable can be used for the next task.

Something like:

```yaml
    - name: get contents of package.txt
      command: "cat packages.txt"
      register: _packages

     - name: RPM Filter
       theforeman.foreman.content_view_filter:
         username: "admin"
         password: "admin"
         server_url: "myhost"
         name: "rpm filter"
         organization: "myorg"
         content_view: "My content view"
         filter_type: "rpm"
         package_name: "{{ item }}"
         inclusion: True
       loop: "{{ _packages.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

[*query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true) the *lines* plugin. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ query('lines', 'cat packages.txt') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item: open-ssh
  item: nginx
  item: grafana
  item: vim
```

See the details about the plugin

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup lines
```